# Why isn't my scanf() not iterating for my for loop on my array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, for-loop

I am working with 1D and 2D arrays but my scanf is not iterating for my loop for my 1D array. Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 int row, col, N, M;

 printf("This program counts occurrences of digits 0 through 9 in an NxM array.\n");
 printf("Enter the size of the array (Row Column): ");
 scanf("%d%d", &N, &M);

 int digits[N][M];

 for (row = 0; row < N; row++){
  printf("Enter row %d: ", row);
  scanf("%d", digits[row][0]);
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing an ampersand in this line  :

> scanf("%d", digits[row][0]);

corrected code :

> scanf("%d", &digits[row][0]);

Comment: If I had a penny for every missing ampersand in scanf...

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
scanf("%d", &digits[row][0]);
```

You need to add "&". This will give address where scanned variable will be stored. It is also the same for storing in array for individual integer.

Answer (score 0):

The last arguments of the scanf must be addresses of variables so if you want to write something in those variables you need to pass them with there addresses not with there values.

scanf("%d",&variable) --> pass with it's address
scanf("%d", variable) --> pass with it's value